# Recommended code in java

Tags: java

How to **subtract the number** using **var-arg method**.
I've written some code but can't get perfect answer....

```
public static double doSubtraction(double... ds)
    {
        double total = 0;
        for(double d : ds)
        {
            total -= d;
        }
        return total;
    }

double subtraction = doSubtraction(1,2,3);
System.out.println("Subtraction : "+subtraction);
```

Actual output: -6

But the expected output is (1-2-3) = -4

Comment: You're subtracting all of your `ds` from zero `(0-1-2-3)`. You need to set `ds[0] = -1 * ds[0]` first, or initialize with `double total = ds[0]` and then skip the first iteration.

Comment: yeah with ds[0] = -1 * ds[0] , the code runs fine thank you so much...

Comment: If you can change the method signature you can use doSubtraction(double from, double... subtracters).  form is the double from which you subtract the subtracters from. This way you removed the empty array edge case.

Answer (score 2):

Two simple approaches:

1. Check if the element is the first one, and add it to total:

   ```
   public static double doSubtraction(double... ds) {
       double total = 0;
       boolean isFirst = true;
       for (double d : ds) {
           if (isFirst) {
               total += d;
               isFirst = false;
           } else {
               total -= d;
           }
       }
       return total;
   }
   ```
2. Initialize the total with the first element, then substract the others:

   ```
   public static double doSubtraction(double... ds) {
       double total = ds[0];
       for (int i = 1 ; i < ds.length ; i++) {
           total -= ds[i];
       }
       return total;
   }
   ```

---

They work fine for your example, but they could have some problems for other inputs:

1. How do you distinguish if the result is `0` because you have `3-2-1` or because you had the default total value?
2. What happens if `ds.length` is `0` in the second example?

To avoid this kind of problems, you could use exceptions. You can create your own exception class or to instantiate an existing one.

E.g.:

```
public static double doSubtraction(double... ds) throws Exception {
    if ( ds.length <= 0 ) {
        throw new Exception("No elements provided");
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are starting from `0`, so the result is `0-1-2-3=-6`;

You probably wanted to re-write the loop as following:

```
double total = ds[0];
for (int i = 1; i < ds.length; i++) {
    total -= ds[i];
}
```

Just pay attention that this code fails if `ds` is empty. I do not know what do you want to return in this case and leave the implementation to you as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Simple math: `0 - 1 = -1;` => `-1 - 2 = -3;` => `-3 - 3 = -6;`

it could never be -4, unless you want the first value as an initial value, i.e. (you're subtracting from 1, 2 & 3.).

```java
public static double doSubtraction(double... ds){
    double total = ds[0];
    for( int i = 1; i < ds.lenght; i++ ) {
        total -= ds[i];
    }

    return total;
}
```

I hope I have helped.

Have a nice day. :)